# How to preserve value type in enum

Tags: enums, f#, attributes, value-type

Let's look at the following piece of code and assume that both `MyAttribute` and `test` function cannot be changed.

```
type MyAttribute() =
    inherit Attribute()

    let mutable prop = null

    member this.Prop
        with get(): obj = prop
        and  set(value) = prop <- value


type MyEnum = 
    | A = 1
    | B = 2

[<My(Prop = MyEnum.B)>]
type MyClass = class
    end

let test () =
   let t = typeof<MyClass>
   let a = t.GetCustomAttributes(false).[0] :?> MyAttribute

   let e = a.Prop
   Convert.ToString(e, Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

I would expect that `test` return `B` but it returns 2. Generated IL code shows that information about enum type is lost and value passed to attribute is just 2.

Is there any way (I guess it should be some attribute) to preserve type in attribute value? Whats more interesting equivalent code in C# works as expected

Equivalent C#:

```
class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public object A { get; set; }
}

enum T { A,B,C }

[My(A = T.A)]
class MyClass
{ }

var a = typeof(MyClass).GetCustomAttributes(false)[0] as MyAttribute;

Convert.ToString(a.A, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Comment: Can you share equivalent C# code you mentioned?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: edited

Comment: You're calling `GetCustomAttributes()` with `false` in F# and `true` in C#; not sure what that does, but it's a difference at least.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev it's just gives attributes from base class. Changed C# version to false - the same result

Comment: It looks like there's a difference between how C# and F# compile enums (or attributes?). If you define all the types in C# and then use them in the `test` function in F#, it also returns the enum case name rather than the integer value.

Comment: Seems like a bug. You should file an issue on [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues).

Comment: I created an issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/995

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing and my knowledge on the internals of the compiler are actually quiet limited but I guess this is something to do with type inference. There is an equivalency between int <-> Enum, and I suspect that the type inference is reducing this to the lowest possible type, in this case int. You can fix this by doing the following

```
open System

type MyAttribute() =
    inherit Attribute()

    let mutable prop = null

    member this.Prop
        with get(): obj = prop
        and  set(value) = prop <- value


type MyEnum = 
    | A = 1
    | B = 2

[<My(Prop = MyEnum.B)>]
type MyClass = class
    end

let test () =
   let t = typeof<MyClass>
   let a = t.GetCustomAttributes(false).[0] :?> MyAttribute

   let e = a.Prop :?> MyEnum //Note
   Convert.ToString(e, Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot change the code responsible for reading that property - it's in another library which has no knowledge about my enum